# Android: setContentView taking up the entire screen

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I have the following code in an activity that receives a string from the main activity:

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
 TextView textView = new TextView(this);
 textView.setTextSize(20);
 textView.setText(message);
// Set the text view as the activity layout
 setContentView(textView);
```

I want to add an image below the `TextView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/serious" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

With the line `setContentView`, the `TextView` takes up the entire screen. Without the line, the image is displayed, but the string says "`false`". Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a mistake , instead of setting setContentView(textView); 
you should use setContentView(R.layout.main);

and create main.xml is res/layout with above mentioned snippet like

```
  <TextView  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/serious" />
```

Answer (score 0):

call

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
```

and then

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); 
textView.setTextSize(20);
textView.setText(message);
```

and it will work.

Comment: Be precise and talk like a developer. What answer do you expect by just saying "my app crashes"? Post the logcat please.